# Date dialog outcome month increase by 1

Tags: android, date, datepicker

I used `DatePickerDialog` with the code below. I retrieve the date of birth of the user in my database and when I open the `dateDialog` it supposed to be the user's date of birth. But when it supposed to be September, it ended up as October. Any idea what causes this and how to fix it?

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {

    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this,
            mDateSetListener,
            mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    switch (id) {

    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

        break;
    }
}   
private void updateDisplay() {
    dateText.setText(
        new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based so add 1

        .append(mMonth +1).append("/")
        .append(mDay).append("/")
        .append(mYear).append(" "));
}

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            dob1 = (monthOfYear + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year);
            if(maxYear - mYear <= 12){
                alertMessage = "User must be above age of 12.";
                dialogBox();
                year = mYear;
            }
            else{
                updateDisplay();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Have you checked the value it's using in `onCreateDialog` and `onPrepareDialog`? Is it 9, 10, or something else?

Comment: I checked the value and it's 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments, it seems you're storing the value as a 1-based index. (Since September is 9, as you said, that means January is 1.) You need to pass in the 0-based index to the `DatePickerDialog`. Simply subtract 1 from your value when it's passed into the constructor (assuming that's where you pull it from the database).

Comment: Yes, January returns as 1. But the value I get from database is 9, once I clicked on the date dialog it appeared as October even though the value is 9. I don't really know what's cause this

Comment: Because 9 is October in a 0-based system. Seriously--when you grab the value from the database, just subtract one.

Comment: I get what you meant. If that's the case, when I subtract one I will get value of 8 and displays as September. But what I want is that the Month (September) to match with the value (9). Because I will be using the data and send to mobile db and server.

Comment: Then your server should recognize the date format as well. You should either store it as 0-based or 1-based *universally* through both your server and client applications, and perform the necessary conversions when doing read/write operations.

Comment: It is store as 1-based in both server and client application. The issue is that when it came out as the month 9 (September), the application automatically assumed it as August because it starts with 0. I don't know how to re-adjust it according to the information return by the server.

Comment: If the server returns 9 for September, subtract one, as I said above. 9 is *one-based* and the `DatePickerDialog` wants a *zero-based* number. I'm not sure how I can make that any clearer.